# c++ add to registry

Tags: c++, registry

So, the code is barking at me, need a bit of help.
Error: char * is incompatible with cost BYTE *.
It's barking at: `RegSetValueExA(hKey, "My App", 0, REG_SZ, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` specifically the buffer.

Error message(vstudio): `Error  3   error C2664: 'RegSetValueExA' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'char [500]' to 'const BYTE *'  {snip}\visual studio 2010\projects\reg\reg\reg.cpp  74`

My code (note: stemres = full path the executable, in LPCWSTR, which I convert successfully to char):

```
HKEY hKey;
RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE, &hKey);
// stemres = the executable path
char buffer[500];
wcstombs(buffer,stemres,500);
RegSetValueExA(hKey, "My App", 0, REG_SZ, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
cout << "Added to registry.";
```

Comment: On which line is it "barking"? And please copy and paste full compiler output.

Comment: RegSetValueExA(hKey, "My App", 0, REG_SZ, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
Specifically: buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifth parameter for `RegSetValueExA()` is `const BYTE *` which should be synonym for `const unsigned char *` and you try to pass `char *` to it. I am afraid you have to convert it:

```
 RegSetValueExA(hKey, "My App", 0, REG_SZ, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE *>(buffer), sizeof(buffer));
```

Comment: OK, that fixed error, but it isn't adding to registry.

Comment: The not adding part was on my stupidity, I forgot it's Windows\CurrentVersion not just CurrentVersion. Solved, thank you!

Comment: @CBMC you should check return value